# create test modules in pytest with the same name as test modules in other packages/directories

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

py.test gives me an "import file mismatch" error.  I believe its because I have test modules with the same name under different packages (see below).

Someone posted an identical question here: [py.test - test discovery failure when tests in different directories are called the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582503).  Unfortunately, none of the responses work for me.

I've also read the manual.  I've tried not including the `__init__.py` files in the test directories per the manual but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

The "app_class1" and "app_class2" directories each contain a test module named test_create.py.

Here is how my code is organized

```
/app
 -setup.py
 /app
  -app.py
  -__init__.py
 /test
  - __init__.py
  /app_class1
   - __init__.py
   - test_create.py
  /app_class2
   - __init__.py
   - test_create.py
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

P.S.  I would have commented on the referenced conversation but my reputation isn't high enough to do so.

Comment: I should mention that I do not understand the "pip install -e" solution to this problem mentioned both in the pytest manual and in the referenced post.  Perhaps this is the solution but I just don't know what it does.  I read the pip manual describing the "-e" flag but was still unclear as to what it does.

Comment: I tried this with the same name and there is no error. Can you post the whole traceback? Files, lines, etc.?

Comment: Strangely, I can no longer replicate the error.  Since posting I installed nose to see if that would work.  I also deleted all the __pycaching__ files but I had already done that several times before posting this question.  Either way thanks for your response.  I'll fiddle around some more to see if I can figure out what fixed the problem.