# InvocationError while running test cases for python using tox

Tags: python, travis-ci, pytest, tox

I am checking the build of my GitHub repository using tox environment but getting "ERROR: InvocationError for command /home/travis/build/path/to/.tox/py27/bin/py.test --basetemp=/home/travis/build/path/to/.tox/py27/tmp (exited with code 5)""

This is a link to my Travis  build for which I am getting an error which I have mentioned above https://travis-ci.org/ashashingadia2996/test_python_20190529/jobs/538667208

Can anyone please explain what's wrong here??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [py.test - test discovery failure when tests in different directories are called the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582503/py-test-test-discovery-failure-when-tests-in-different-directories-are-called)

Comment: @phd, But I didn't find the solution to my problem from anywhere

Comment: @AshaShinagadia you have `test_api_key.py` in project root and `test_api_key.py` in `tests`. Both modules are identical, but are in different locations. You need to keep your tests in a more organized way.

Comment: @hoefling, corrected my mistake and removed extra test file from the repository but still getting some error for python version 3.3